# WordPress Dynamic.ooo Dynamic Posts Template not reflecting on Live Website

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently encountering some issues with the website I'm working on. I've created a template for my dynamic posts using Dynamic.ooo. However, the problem is that it's not reflecting on the live website, although it appears correctly in Elementor. This issue is the primary concern affecting the entire website, and it's not limited to just the Dynamic.ooo plugin; some features of WordPress also fail to reflect on the live website.

I've attempted to clear the cache and update the Dynamic.ooo plugin, but unfortunately, the update process fails. I am using Dynamic.ooo version 2.12.0